# Use integer to set color

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the method `Color.FromArgb(Int32)` to assign the `BackColor` for some controls, but shows no color no matter the number I use. I think that I'm wrong in how I use it and it's a very simple thing, can someone explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Color.FromArgb Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx)  inverse of / complements [Color.ToArgb Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx use something like `Color.FromArgb(0x00...)` but I need to use just a number.

Comment: like `Color.FromArgb(1234)`

Comment: Read the words on MSDN - they explain that `The byte-ordering of the 32-bit ARGB value is AARRGGBB.`  its not a simple integer map like 4 = Red

Comment: the alpha (transparency) channel should not be set to 0 `Color.FromArgb(0xFF000000 + 1234)` you can check some of the color constants here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/KnownColors.cs

Comment: Plutonix Slai Thanks I got it now.